# Double Virtual OS

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, openvz

Is it possible to run openvz in VirtualBox ?

Simply , I want to do this.
operation system on my Real Computer is Windows (This is not virtual) 
In Windows I installed Virtual Box and installed Cent Os to virtual box . 
Now I installed openvz to Centos (it works)
Centos is host OS for openvz. I want to install fedora to openvz as virtual OS . 
I can't do it , openvz gives me errors.

I want to ask that , it is possible to run  Virtual operation system in openvz where openvz is installed to Virtual Box ?

Comment: What do you mean by `install fedora to openvz as virtual OS`? Which layer structure is what you want ? Windows -> CentOS -> Fedora , or Windows -> CentOS -> OpenVZ -> Fedora ?

Comment: this structure, 
Windows -> Virtual Box -> CentOS -> OpenVZ -> Fedora  

OpenVz installed on CentOS , CentOS is host OS for openvz